# playframework scala validate case class in tests

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Hi I try to validate in a test the test result in my scala playframework application.

My code looks like this:

```
implicit val clientIdFormat = Json.format[clientId]

case class clientId(id: Int)
```

and in the test:

```
  val content = contentAsJson(result).validate(clientId).asOpt.orNull
```

error is type mismatch

[image]

what could be my fail in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `validate` expects a *type parameter*, not an argument:

```
def validate[A](implicit rds: Reads[A]): JsResult[A] = rds.reads(this)
```

So, you should call it using `[clientId]` and not `(clientId)`:

```
val content = contentAsJson(result).validate[clientId].asOpt.orNull
```

Comment: What's the value of such tests? That's already part of the test coverage of Play itself.